# How to read a file which is on server using perl script

Tags: perl, perforce, perl-module

I have a file on my perforce client which i can read from the client but i want to read it from the depot instead from my client and i Have to achieve this using a Perl script and my client name is ata and its root directory is /home/ata/hw
The following code is written for the file on my client

```
my $clients_file="/home/ata/hw/hard/ip/golden_design_map.cfg";
open(READ,"<$clients_file") or die "Couldn't open the file for reading:$!";
```

But this is what i want to achieve

```
my $clients_file="//hw/hard/ip/golden_design_map.cfg";
open(READ,"<$clients_file") or die "Couldn't open the file for reading:$!";
```

Here //hw/hard/ip/golden_design_map.cfg is the file on the depot or the server.
Is there any module which i can use.Any help is truly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [**File::Remote**](http://search.cpan.org/~nwiger/File-Remote-1.17/Remote.pm) module.

Synopsis:

```
use File::Remote;

# read from a remote file
open(REMOTE, "host:/remote/file") or die $!;
print while (<REMOTE>);
close(REMOTE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the p4 command line like this:

```
open( READ, "p4 print -q $clients_file|" ) or die "Couldn't execute p4:$!";
```

This assumes that your environment is already set up to run p4 commands (p4 executable in the PATH, valid settings for P4PORT and P4USER, valid login ticket acquired by having run "p4 login" previously, etc).

Or you can use the Perforce Perl module:  http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/02_perl.html